# Qt widget failing to repaint under certain conditions

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am having a strange issue with a widget failing to repaint for a long time.

I have one non-Qt thread that plays audio and periodically posts a custom event to my GUI thread, based on audio playback position.  The GUI thread reacts by generating some visual feedback (e.g., display label on top of a widget) and invoking repaint() on itself.  This works great on Mac OSX and it works fine within a unit test application I have that exercises the functionality on Windows (XP & 7), however, the widget does not properly repaint in my real application, on Windows XP/7, until the audio playback finishes.

Proper behaviour observed on OSX and within my unit test:

```
-> Custom Event
-> QEvent::Paint (12)
-> Custom Event
-> QEvent::Paint (12)
etc.
```

Wrong behaviour observed in my actual application:

```
-> Custom Event 
-> QEvent::UpdateRequest (77)
-> Custom Event  
-> QEvent::UpdateRequest (77)
etc.
-> QEvent::Paint (12)
```

I have tried various things to force the repaint to occur, e.g., QCoreApplication::processEvents, but all to no avail.  I have also tried eliminating the inter-thread events as a culprit and used a periodic timer to poll the current audio position from the GUI thread and update the widget, also without much luck.

Any ideas on how to further diagnose this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you call update() or repaint()?

Comment: I have tried both update and repaint.

Comment: Is it possible to show some of your code here? maybe just the main() on Windows?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is systemic and does not occur when I pull the relevant parts out into a stand-alone unit test.  Threading may be an issue here.  I believe that the audio thread runs at a higher priority than the Qt GUI thread.  However, this does not seem to prevent the custom event from being received.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling the paint event handler directly? i.e. `paintEvent(NULL)`?

Comment: Good idea.  I'll try that tonight.

Comment: No luck with this.  Calling paintEvent() directly does not seem to make a difference.